# SQL Query with Date, Child and Sweets eaten

Tags: sql, database

I have a question like this
[image]

I'm not sure how to solve this

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide data in the consumable format ?

Comment: INSERT INTO newtable (
    Date,
    Child,
    SweetsEaten)
VALUES
    ('1/01/2022',
        'Tom',
        3),
    ('2/01/2022',
        'Jane',
        2),
    ('11/01/2022',
        'Leslie',
        1),
    ('14/02/2022',
        'Tom',
        0),
    ('18/02/2022',
        'Jane',
        5),
    ('1/02/2022',
        'Leslie',
        1),
    ('7/03/2022',
        'Leslie',
        3
    ),
    (
        '9/03/2022',
        'Tom',
        2),
    ('18/03/2022',
        'Jane',
        0); @Sergey

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS newtable;
CREATE TABLE newtable
(
  DateD DATE NOT NULL,
  Child VARCHAR(10)NOT NULL,
  SweetsEaten TINYINT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO newtable ( DateD, Child, SweetsEaten) 
VALUES ('20220101', 'Tom', 3), 
       ('20220102', 'Jane', 2), 
       ('20220111', 'Leslie', 1), 
       ('20220214', 'Tom', 0), 
       ('20220218', 'Jane', 5), 
       ('20220201', 'Leslie', 1), 
       ('20220307', 'Leslie', 3 ), 
       ( '20220309', 'Tom', 2), 
       ('20220318', 'Jane', 0);
   SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM
   (
     SELECT N.DateD,N.Child,N.SweetsEaten,
      SUM(N.SweetsEaten)OVER(PARTITION BY N.Child ORDER BY N.DateD ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)XCOL  
     FROM newtable AS N
   ) X WHERE X.XCOL>=5
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY X.Child ORDER BY XCOL ASC);
```

Hope the above is suitable for you (SQL Server 2017)

Comment: I'm getting error at INSERT
[22:01:46] Error while executing SQL query on database 'New database': near "INSERT": syntax error

Comment: Could you please clarify what RDBMS you use?

Answer (score 1):

The inner from is the cumulative sum of sweets, so you only need to select the first occurrence, `MIN(Date)`, when the cumulative sum is greater then 5.

```
SELECT

    Child,
    MIN(Date)

FROM    (
        SELECT  
            Child,
            DATE,
            SUM(SweetsEaten) OVER(PARTITION BY Child ORDER BY Date) AS SweetsEatenToDate
        FROM table1
        )

WHERE SweetsEatenToDate >= 5
GROUP BY Child
```

The cumulative sum reads like this:
Your `SUMing` all the sweets `PARTIONing` them `BY` Child `ORDERed BY` Date